# Nth dimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a arrays inside array of number in java, Now I want to print this array in linear way. So how to traverse over it?
Eg:

```
[1,[4,6],[4,9,1,[34,[56,32,45,87]],56,7],98]
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Can you show us how this array is defined?

Comment: I have only the given information. the declaration way of array should be  same as like we use to declare other array.

Comment: This should be a 2 dimensional array. Iterate the 2 dimensional array to traverse the items

Comment: no it is more then 2 dimentional.

Comment: Arrays.asList(nameOfYourArray)

Comment: How you are constructing such array in Java? It is not easy to construct such arrays using standard Array class. You must think of using collections like ArrayList, List etc..

Comment: @Jayaprasad, yes u r right. That is not an easy task. must think before create it.

Comment: You should provide at least the data structure used here. it is neither N'th dimentional array nor Array of Arrays.

Comment: @Dev so your question also include How to create such a data structure ?

Comment: @naveejr yes question nothing have more the I have provided inforation, Suppose u have a task like it, Then how we create such kind of array and how we print after that?

Answer (score 2):

A simple recursion will do the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create the array: [1, [2, 3], 4]
        Object[] arr = new Object[3];
        arr[0] = 1;
        arr[1] = new Object[2];
        arr[2] = 4;
        ((Object[])arr[1])[0] = 2;
        ((Object[])arr[1])[1] = 3;

        // print
        printArr(arr);
    }

    // print the array in order - recursively 
    static void printArr(Object[] arr) {
        for (Object i : arr) {
            if (i instanceof Integer) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
            else {
                printArr((Object[])i);
            }
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be `Arrays.deepToString(array)`.

Comment: -1 actually this method will turn the nested array into a "string": meaning that `[1, [2, 3], 4]` will be printed as "[1, [2, 3], 4]" not as "1 2 3 4"

Comment: @alfasin Was OP looking for printing an array in a particular format?

Comment: That's what he wrote: "I want to print this array in linear way"

Comment: @alfasin I'm not quite sure if `deepToString()`'s output is in some non-linear way, but I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution:

You need a datastructure (Tree) to hold this data:

```
public class ArrayHolder {

private boolean isLeaf;
private int number;
private List<ArrayHolder> nodes;

public ArrayHolder(int number) {
    isLeaf = true;
    this.number = number;
}

public ArrayHolder() {
    isLeaf = false;
    nodes = new ArrayList<ArrayHolder>();
}

public boolean isLeaf() {
    return isLeaf;
}

public void addNode(ArrayHolder node) {
    nodes.add(node);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (isLeaf) {
        sb.append(number + ",");
    } else {
        sb.append("[ ");
        for (ArrayHolder arrayHolder : nodes) {
            sb.append(arrayHolder.toString());
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        sb.append("]");
        sb.append(",");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

TestCase:

```
   // [1,[4,6],[4,[34],56,7],98]

    ArrayHolder[] elements = new ArrayHolder[8];
    elements[0] = new ArrayHolder(1);
    elements[1] = new ArrayHolder(4);
    elements[2] = new ArrayHolder(6);
    elements[3] = new ArrayHolder(4);
    elements[4] = new ArrayHolder(34);
    elements[5] = new ArrayHolder(56);
    elements[6] = new ArrayHolder(7);
    elements[7] = new ArrayHolder(98);

    ArrayHolder root = new ArrayHolder();
    root.addNode(elements[0]);

    ArrayHolder arr46 = new ArrayHolder();
    arr46.addNode(elements[1]);
    arr46.addNode(elements[2]);
    root.addNode(arr46);

    ArrayHolder arr434567 = new ArrayHolder();
    arr434567.addNode(new ArrayHolder(4));
    ArrayHolder arr34 = new ArrayHolder();
    arr34.addNode(new ArrayHolder(34));
    arr434567.addNode(arr34);
    arr434567.addNode(new ArrayHolder(56));
    arr434567.addNode(new ArrayHolder(7));
    root.addNode(arr434567);

    root.addNode(new ArrayHolder(98));

    System.out.println(root);
```

Comment: Yes right Mr.Naveejr, I have got same idea to solve this prob using tree structure described by Donald knuth vol 1.